# jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery

I am writing a javascript file for an ASP.NET web app used by many people. This file will use jQuery, so to ensure I can safely use the $ alias, the file is structured like this:

```
(function ($) {
  // My javascript here can safely use the $ alias
})(jquery);
```

However, my Firebug console is showing the error "jQuery is not defined". I made sure the script tag for this file comes *after* the script tag for jQuery, but clearly this script is running before jQuery is ready.

How can I ensure the script runs after jQuery is ready?

Comment: Didn't you type a lowercase `jquery`?

Comment: To expand on @meder's (**+1**) comment, the last line should be: [`})(jQuery);`](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery)

Comment: try `jQuery` the case is important

Comment: Can you confirm that you've correctly linked to the .js file for jQuery?

Comment: The jQuery object is `jQuery`.  Lower case `j`, upper case `Q`.  Make sure you have it in the correct case in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identifiers in Javascript are case-sensitive.

The variable `jquery` doesn't exist, but `jQuery` does.

```
(function ($) {
  // My javascript here can safely use the $ alias
})(jQuery);
```

---

**To address your doubts about when scripts are executed**:

> The execution of scripts waits for external scripts to be loaded.

The jQuery script will always be loaded and executed before the browser continues with script later in the page. (Unless of course the jQuery script fails to load altogether.)

Comment: i would add: make sure jquery is inserted before your script ;)

Comment: D'oh! Yes, it was a case sensitivity problem. That's what can happen when you copy and paste code. Thanks so much!